# Did View's draw method can run on background thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, view, background, draw

I want to capture screen on background thread.So I use a thread to do this job,like this:

```
private void captureScreen(final Context context) {
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View view = ((Activity) context).findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            if (null != bmp) {
                view.draw(new Canvas(bmp));
                stack.push(bmp);                            
            }
        }
    }.start();       
}
```

most time there is no problem, but sometimes this will crash caused by "only original thread can touch this", so make view.draw() run on other thread is right things to do or did you have better method to capture screen on background thread?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you do your code not in UI thread.
Android provides several ways to use UI thread:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       captureScreen();
    }
});
```

or

```
MainActivity.this.myView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       captureScreen();
    }
});
```

and

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

   .......

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
       captureScreen(result);
    }
}
```

And you need to refactor your `captureScreen();` method to not create new Thread() just do screenshot.

Comment: thanks anyway, but I want do it on background thread, not UI thread, so screen capture won't take UI thread's resource.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to update View elements not in UI thread. You can crate bitmap in background but "view.draw(new Canvas(bmp));"must be in UI thread.